# How can I deserialize Array of Arrays in Newtonsoft Json C#?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I have a Json array string:

```
data = "[[2, 3, 32],[6,19,7],[17,19,10]]";
```

I would like it to serialize it by Newtonsoft json. So I made a class:

```
    public class Root
{
    public List<List<int>> MyArray { get; set; }
}
```

But this code is giving me an error:

```
List<Root> deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(e.data);
```

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Root' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: You can't deserialize to a scalar object if your JSON represents an array. You must deserialize to a collection. So you should `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<int>>>(e.data)` instead of  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(e.data)`

Comment: Its not working. I change it to:
var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<int>>>(e.data);
and im getting:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value 2 to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 2. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32].
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable (System.Object value, System.Type initialType, System.Type targetType) [0x00062] in <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>

Comment: [Works on my machine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6WwoHx). Is your data actually different than what you've shown in the question, and thus your numbers are too big for an int?

Comment: I lost one character in my string when I was testing. It works now perfectly! Thank you so much for your help mason!